# Is it possible to collapse multiple views in AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, coordinator-layout

I have an AppBarLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout, two views below and ViewPager at the rest of the screen

```xml
<Coordinator>

    <AppBarLayout>
        // Toolbar stuff inside
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"/>

        // Should collapse by design
        <FirstButtonView app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

        <TabLayout app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    </AppBarLayout>

    <ViewPager app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</Coordinator>
```

With this layout it collapsed toolbar as expected, but both views are being pinned to the top

As i see in AppBarLayout class, when it calculates possible scroll, it iterates through child views until meet flag SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED=2, then breaks the loop

```java
public final int getTotalScrollRange() {
        if (this.totalScrollRange != -1) {
            return this.totalScrollRange;
        } else {
            int range = 0;
            int i = 0;

            for(int z = this.getChildCount(); i < z; ++i) {
                View child = this.getChildAt(i);
                AppBarLayout.LayoutParams lp = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams)child.getLayoutParams();
                int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                int flags = lp.scrollFlags;
                if ((flags & 1) == 0) {
                    break;
                }

                range += childHeight + lp.topMargin + lp.bottomMargin;
                if ((flags & 2) != 0) {
                    range -= ViewCompat.getMinimumHeight(child);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return this.totalScrollRange = Math.max(0, range - this.getTopInset());
        }
    }
```

Is it possible somehow to solve it?
[Target design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcaow.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Documentation on using "SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL", "**If any sibling views before this one do not have this flag, then this value has no effect.**"

Hence the same flag has to be used with other siblings.